# Possible bug in python. Create decorator to automatically generate properties

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator

I've created a `repl.it` to run the code online:
https://repl.it/repls/ShimmeringQuickwittedHarddrive#main.py

---

I am trying to create a decorator to "carry" properties from the object's attribute into the object.
simplistic example (pseudo code):

```
class carry:
    ''' Decorator. '''
    class Prop:
        ''' Representation of '@property'. '''
        # impl
    # impl

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self._val_0 = 'A: val_0'
        self._val_1 = 'A: val_1'
    @property
    def val_0(self):
        return self._val_0
    @property
    def val_1(self):
        return self._val_1

# '_a'              - the name of the attribute to get the @property'ies from.
# 'carry.Prop(...)' - a list of @property'ies to carry.
@carry(
    '_a',
    carry.Prop('val_0'),
    carry.Prop('val_1')
)
class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self._a = A()
```

what I expect to get:

```
>>> b = B()
>>> print(b.val_0)
'A: val_0'
>>> print(b.val_1)
'A: val_1'
```

what I am getting:
(warning: the difference is quite subtle and easy to miss; `b.val_0` returns the value of `b.val_1`)

```
>>> b = B()
>>> print(b.val_0)
'A: val_1'
>>> print(b.val_1)
'A: val_1'
```

Code below is an "executable" minimalistic sample to reproduces the error.
it's a lot of code so I split it into three sections:

- Decorator:
  Implementation of the decortor.
  Error occurs somewhere inside `carry.__call__()`.
- Tests:
  'print-debug' tests of the `@carry` decorator.
  It's important to notice that when I'm printing `b.val_0`, instead of getting `val_0` I am getting the last `@property`'s representation that was passed into the `@carry` ctor.
  To me it seems like writing `setattr(<parrent>, <name>, property(<fget, fset, fdel>))` is bugged somewhere inside python. and instead of creating a `property()` i am wanting it creates, it overwrites them.

```
import pprint

from copy import copy

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(
    indent = 2,
    width = 80, 
    depth = None, 
    compact = False,
    sort_dicts = False
)

##################################################
# Decorator:
##################################################

class carry:
    class Prop:
        ''' Represents a 'property'. '''
        def __init__(self, name:str, fget:bool=True, fset:bool=False, fdel:bool=False):
            self._name = name
            self._fget = fget
            self._fset = fset
            self._fdel = fdel
        @property
        def name(self) -> str:
            return self._name
        @property
        def fget(self) -> bool:
            return self._fget
        @property
        def fset(self) -> bool:
            return self._fset
        @property
        def fdel(self) -> bool:
            return self._fdel

    def __init__(self, obj, *props):
        self._obj = obj
        self._props = props

    def __call__(self, cls):
        class Template(cls):
            pass
        Template.__name__ = cls.__name__
        Template.__doc__  = cls.__doc__

        for prop in self._props:
            print('prop repr: ... {}'.format(prop.__dict__))

            kwargs = {}
            if prop.fget:
                def fget(self):
                    print('fget id: ..... {}'.format(id(fget)))
                    print('fget addr: ... {}'.format(hex(id(fget))))
                    print('fget.obj: .... {}'.format(fget.obj))
                    print('fget.name: ... {}'.format(fget.name))
                    return getattr(getattr(self, fget.obj), fget.name)
                fget.obj  = copy(self._obj)
                fget.name = copy(prop.name)
                print('fget id: ..... {}'.format(id(fget)))
                print('fget addr: ... {}'.format(hex(id(fget))))
                print('fget.obj: .... {}'.format(fget.obj))
                print('fget.name: ... {}'.format(fget.name))
                kwargs['fget'] = fget

            result = property(**kwargs)
            print('kwargs: ...... {}'.format(kwargs))
            print('prop: ........ {}'.format(result))
            print('prop id: ..... {}'.format(id(result)))
            print('prop addr: ... {}'.format(hex(id(result))))
            setattr(Template, prop.name, result)
            print()

        # Return modified class:
        return Template

##################################################
# Tests:
##################################################

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self._val_0 = 'A: val_0: 0'
        self._val_1 = 'A: val_1: 1'
        self._val_2 = 'A: val_2: 2'
        self._val_3 = 'A: val_3: 3'
    @property
    def val_0(self):
        return self._val_0
    @property
    def val_1(self):
        return self._val_1
    @property
    def val_2(self):
        return self._val_2
    @property
    def val_3(self):
        return self._val_3

print()
print('##################################################')
print()

props = [
    carry.Prop('val_0'),
    carry.Prop('val_1'),
    carry.Prop('val_2'),
    carry.Prop('val_3'),
]

@carry('_a', *props)
class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self._a = A()

print('##################################################')
print()

print(B)
print(B.__name__)
pp.pprint(dir(B))

print()
print('##################################################')
print()

b = B()
print(b.val_0)
print()
print(b.val_1)
print()
print(b.val_2)
print()
print(b.val_3)
print()
```

Comment: can you make the example a bit more minimalistic?

Comment: @Marat I tried to make it more minimalistic, however, the whole decorator revolves around `carry.__call__(self, cls)` function. That's its backbone. Entire logic happens in there. The best I can do is to remove dependencies and re-write parts which depend on them.

Comment: I've edited the code as much as I could + I've created a `repl.it` to edit the code onine

Comment: This looks like a "delegate" pattern. Here is some alternative code for that: https://www.michaelcho.me/article/method-delegation-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let me reiterate my comment: You appear to be implementing a "delegate" pattern. Here is some code that does that with fewer lines and more flexibility:
https://www.michaelcho.me/article/method-delegation-in-python

The name 'carry' does not tell me what to expect. Unless you have some problem domain where that name is already well-established, I would urge you to consider a different name. With that said ...

I believe your problem is that you are trying to *use* a closure without *creating* a closure. The loop that you have for iterating over all the properties is not a proper closure, and so there is leakage-- all references end up pointing to the last value of the iteration variables.

I modified your example code like this:

```
        if prop.fget:
            fget = self.make_fget(self._obj, prop.name)
            #def fget(self):
            #    print('fget id: ..... {}'.format(id(fget)))
            #    print('fget addr: ... {}'.format(hex(id(fget))))
            #    print('fget.obj: .... {}'.format(fget.obj))
            #    print('fget.name: ... {}'.format(fget.name))
            #    return getattr(getattr(self, fget.obj), fget.name)
            #fget.obj  = copy(self._obj)
            #fget.name = copy(prop.name)
```

And added this method:

```
def make_fget(self, attribute_name, property_name):
    """ Construct and return an fget closure. """
    def fget(self):
        print('fget id: ..... {}'.format(id(fget)))
        print('fget addr: ... {}'.format(hex(id(fget))))
        print('fget.obj: .... {}'.format(fget.obj))
        print('fget.name: ... {}'.format(fget.name))
        return getattr(getattr(self, fget.obj), fget.name)

    fget.obj = attribute_name
    fget.name = property_name
    return fget
```

The result was more what I think you expect:

```
# ... many, many lines elided ...

fget id: ..... 139848106927168
fget addr: ... 0x7f30ecbc6440
fget.obj: .... _a
fget.name: ... val_0
A: val_0: 0

fget id: ..... 139848106463104
fget addr: ... 0x7f30ecb54f80
fget.obj: .... _a
fget.name: ... val_1
A: val_1: 1

fget id: ..... 139848106491984
fget addr: ... 0x7f30ecb5c050
fget.obj: .... _a
fget.name: ... val_2
A: val_2: 2

fget id: ..... 139848106492128
fget addr: ... 0x7f30ecb5c0e0
fget.obj: .... _a
fget.name: ... val_3
A: val_3: 3
```

Comment: Thank you very much! All three; the comment, the answer and the reason (loop to iterate over properties is not a proper closure -> "leakage" -> all references point to the variables from the last iteration) are on the mark. I spend an entire day trying to debug my code, without any clue what was wrong. Now I need to learn about python's closures because that's the 1st time I encountered them <ashamed>. Once again thank you very much!